# How do you make a Kohana website portable?

Tags: php, kohana

I just finished coding an online portal with [Kohana PHP](http://kohanaphp.com/).

It works fine on my PC, but when I tried to host it on another server, "BONK!",
it shows up without displaying the pictures of the products.

I don't even know what's going on.

What rules I should follow to make my Kohana apps portable?

Answer (score 3):

I'm using Kohana to develop a few websites and here are some tricks that I use to make sure that the websites are portable, as in I can just upload the files from my development environment into the server and have them running without having to modify anything:

1. Use the same directory structure. For example in my case I put the Kohana core folders into `<drive><somepath>/apps/kohana/system/` and `<drive><somepath>/apps/kohana/modules/` on my local disk and `/apps/kohana/system/` and `/apps/kohana/modules/` on the server. Similarly, I set my local XAMPP htdocs to `<drive><somepath>/public_html/` to follow the server setting of `/public_html`. That way I don't have to modify `index.php` when I upload it to the server. **Use relative paths**.
2. Like kfederov suggested, use `url::base()` in all your src=".." in your templates. The way I do it is by assigning `$this->template->baseurl = url::base();` in my Controller_Template (I'm using Kohana 3 but the method is almost the same for Kohana 2.x) and use `{$baseurl}` in the Smarty templates (I highly recommend using Smarty template system -- you can find the module in the Kohana forum).
3. Use the same database name, username and password in both development and server environment so that I don't have to modify `config/database.php`, obviously.
4. If you are hosting multiple websites with different domains on the same hosting, obviously you cannot use `/public_html` as the document root for all but one of the websites. You most probably have to configure those non-primary domains to point to different folders, for example in my case I put them in `/hosted/*/` folders and configure my server cPanel accordingly. To duplicate this setting in your local environment, you need to use localhost subdomains, which requires you to modify `httpd.conf` and your HOSTS file accordingly, as below:

   1. Add Virtual Host in `httpd.conf`. e.g:

      > ```
      > <VirtualHost *:80>
      >   DocumentRoot /path/to/hosted/coolwebsite
      >   ServerName coolwebsite.localhost
      > </VirtualHost>
      > ```
   2. Add to your HOSTS file (`C:\WINDOWS\system32\drivers\etc\hosts` if under Windows):

      > ```
      > 127.0.0.1     coolwebsite.localhost
      > ```
   3. Now you use `http://coolwebsite.localhost/` to access the website on locally running web server for your development environment.

Hope this helps!

Comment: +1. For your #2: You could also put a `<base>` tag in the head of your layout like this: `<base href="<?php echo URL::base(TRUE) ?>">` and let the browser prepend the base URL for you on every asset URL instead of making a `URL::base()` call for every asset. Bye.

Answer (score 0):

Be sure to update your .htaccess, values in your index.php and, perhaps, in your configuration files.

Comment: Certain configuration fields may need the absolute path of the website AFAIR.

Comment: I think you could add the code snippets where the code needs to be modified.

Answer (score 0):

1. Check your `.htaccess` and `bootstrap.php` files for the right site path.
2. Make sure you used `URL::base()` in `src="..."`.

Comment: Could you give an example of number 2?